# Java remove button

Tags: java

[This is how the GUI looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMtRX.png)
I have a GUI program that stores user's details (such as salary, fname, lname, date) into an arraylist using an add button. After the user presses add, the user presses list to output all the information into a panel.

My full code is below.

```
public class EmploymentRecords extends javax.swing.JFrame {

ArrayList <Data> Output = new ArrayList <Data>();
```

Add button:

```
private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    
    Data d;
    
    String id, firstName, lastName, salary, startDate;
    
    id = txtID.getText();
    firstName = txtFName.getText();
    lastName = txtLName.getText();
    salary = txtSalary.getText();
    startDate = txtDate.getText();
    
    d = new Data(id, firstName, lastName, salary, startDate);
    Output.add(d);
    
}
```

List Button:

```
private void btnListActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    
    String print = "";
    for (int i=0; i<=Output.size()-1; i++) 
    {
        print = print + "ID #:" + Output.get(i).id + ", "
                + Output.get(i).firstName + " "
                + Output.get(i).lastName + ", "
                + "$" + Output.get(i).salary + ", "
                + Output.get(i).startDate + "\n ";
    }
    pnlOutput.setText(print);
    
    
}
```

Remove Button:

```
private void btnRemoveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    
    int index;
    String id = txtID.getText();
    boolean idCheck = Output.contains(id);

    if (idCheck == true){
        index = Output.indexOf(id);
        Output.remove(index);
    }
    else {
        lblError.setText("Employee not found. Please try again.");
    }
```

Data Class:

```
class Data {
    String id, firstName, lastName, salary, startDate;
    Data (String _id, String _firstName, String _lastName, String _salary, String _startDate) {
        id = _id;
        firstName = _firstName;
        lastName = _lastName;
        salary = _salary;
        startDate = _startDate;
    }
}
```

I have everything working such as the list and add button, but my problem is with the Remove button: The user has a button to remove a single employees data from the arraylist based on only writing the the ID in the text area, which also removes all the information outputted to the user in the panel. My code above for the remove button doesnt work and when I press remove, nothing happens and the data stays there in the output panel.

Id really appreciate any help I get on this remove button

Comment: In **btnRemoveActionPerformed** method add a printing statement like, employee is removed. then run the program, One of the print statement should get executed

Comment: @MohamedShabeerkp ive done that, I want to remove the employees data from the output panel as well. Just like i added to it in the add/list button

Comment: IMHO, the problem is, that you are comparing `Data` and `String` objects. In `btnRemoveActionPerformed`, `id` is a String, but your array contains `Data` objects, so `idCheck` will never be true and `indexOf` would not return anything. Quick and dirty solution: Iterate over `Output` to find the element with the id and then remove it. Cleaner way: Use kind of a map (id -> data).

Comment: Im an amateur programmer. Are you able to show me the solution?

Comment: loop through `Output` list and check if `Output.get(i).getId().equals(txtID.getText())`. If thats true, then you found the entry you want to remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses the streaming API:

```java
private void btnRemoveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    
    int index;
    String id = txtID.getText();

    List<Data> elementsWithId = Output.stream() // Use the streaming API on Output
      .filter(data -> data.id.equals(id)) // filter out the element(s) with matching id
      .collect(Collectors.toList()); // put the findings into a new list

    boolean idCheck = (elementsWithId.size() > 0);

    if (idCheck == true){
      for (Data data: elementsWithId) {
        Output.remove(data);
      }
    }
    else {
        lblError.setText("Employee not found. Please try again.");
    }

    // Pass the event on to the list functionality:
    btnListActionPerformed(evt);
}
```

So, the real "magic" happens in the commented lines. You'll search the whole `Output` list for elements with the given ID and create a new list containing the matches only. (I understood, there should be one at most, but you never know...)

The rest is quite the same as you had it before, just that we're working with the result list here.

Please note, that there are serveral approaches to your problem and this is just one the quick and easy ones. There are more elaborate ones for sure.

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty understandable. However, when I press the remove button, nothing happens and that employee's information is still in the panel.

Comment: I attached a picture of how the GUI looks, please take a look at that. You can see the panel at the bottum

Comment: Hmmm, I can't see any mistake there. Is the "Employee not found..." text displayed? Additionally, you could try and add some more debug messages. And what happens if you click on the "list" Button - will the removed id still be there?

Comment: Oh this does work. When I press remove, then list, the id is removed. But I wanted it to be removed by just pressing the remove button without pressing the list button.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer with one more quick and dirty fix. ;) --> Just passing the event on to the "list" call.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks :)